# google add menu title before content in that menu

Tags: html, seo, meta, microdata

main address blog is:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/p1
http://www.example.com/p2
.
.
.
```

---

and also I have some other page blog style for example for most view articls.

for example this is for most views in week:

```
http://www.example.com/w
http://www.example.com/w1
http://www.example.com/w2
http://www.example.com/w3
.
.
.
```

and the menu title for first page is: **Most week**

(**note**: this is title of menu that target to `'http://www.example.com/w'` ...not title of `'http://www.example.com/w'`!

---

so I have two type of blog with duplicate content...right? (of course address of content is unique!)

One is main...to show content order according last time for all content!(order by last time)

and another just show most view for all content again!
(order by most view in week)
.
.

and all url content format is like this:  `http://www.example.com/123`

This is my problem:

google add **most weekend** to most of my artilcs header...I think google think it's section!

for example:    `this is my content articls - most week`

how can I tell google this is wrong?

for example do you suggest me I use `no-follow` or `no-index` for all most-week pages?

dose have microdata (sechema.org) a tool to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO and not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

The task isn't clear for me. But

1) If you use similar content - use "canonical" tag

2) Google can't put the "Most week" to the page, if it doesn't have it

3) Pay attention to internal linking

It will be great if you give a real example!